# Add data from two columns based on full outer join result

Tags: sql, teradata, outer-join

My data from Full outer join looks like this. I am trying to build an sql query to do the following.

1. ha and da are same values but any one can be None
2. Do hc+dc ( Consider hc or dc as 0 when it is None)

My data looks like this.

[image: My data from full outer join looks like this]

I am expecting result like this

[image]

Query I am trying:

```
select 
(case when h.ha not in ('None') then h.ha else h.da end) as acc,
(case when h.hc not in ('None') then cast(h.hc as integer) else 0 end 
 + 
case when h.dc not in ('None') then cast(h.dc as integer) else 0 end) as tc 
from 

(select h.acc as ha, hc, d.acc as da, dc from h_data h
full outer join
d_data d
on h.acc = d.acc
) h
```

I am getting `A character string failed conversion to a numeric value` Not sure where I am making a mistake.

Comment: I think you are confusing `'None'` with `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use teradata though your example looks to me your idea is correct, you only treat `null`s wrong. I guess `None` is just some presentation of `null` in your db browser. Standard `coalesce` function IMHO does the job:

```
with h_data as (
  select 'AA' as acc, 1 as hc union
  select 'BB' as acc, 1 as hc union
  select 'EE' as acc, 1 as hc union
  select 'FF' as acc, 2 as hc union
  select 'GG' as acc, 1 as hc union
  select 'HH' as acc, 1 as hc
), d_data as (
  select 'CC' as acc, 1 as dc union
  select 'DD' as acc, 1 as dc union
  select 'EE' as acc, 2 as dc union
  select 'GG' as acc, 4 as dc
)
select coalesce(h.acc, d.acc) as acc,
  coalesce(h.hc, 0) + coalesce(d.dc, 0) as tc
from h_data h
full outer join d_data d on h.acc = d.acc
order by 1
```

[Tested on PG.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/33325)

Comment: Thanks @Tomas! My bad. Misinterpreted null as none. My query worked checking with null. I will try coalesce it looks simple